# What verb goes with "degree project"?

Tags: word-request, verbs

As the heading says: what would be the best verb to use with "degree project"? **Do** a degree project? **Carry out** a degree project? **Write** a degree project? Something else entirely?

Examples:

> The student should VERB a degree project that meets the course objectives.

> The supervisor should guide the student through all the stages of VERBing a degree project.

As always, I'm very grateful for any help I can get here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a project is "done", it's *completed* - and that would be a good generic verb to use in the sentences you provide.

If you only care if the student does some of the work on the project, instead of completing or being responsible for the end state of the product, the phrase you're looking for is *contribute to*.

> The student should *complete* (or *contribute to*) a degree project that meets the course objectives.

> The supervisor should guide the student through all the stages of *completing* (or *contributing to*) a degree project.